# Testing Singleton Class with Jest throws in get instance

Tags: typescript, singleton, ts-jest

I'm trying to test this Singleton class:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

interface Configuration {
  port: number
  gamesExternalAPIURL: string
}

export default class Config {
  private static instance: Config | null = null
  private readonly config: Configuration

  private constructor() {
    this.config = this.getConfigFromEnv()
  }

  get() {
    return this.config
  }

  static getInstance() {
    if (Config.instance === null) {
      Config.instance = new Config()
    }

    return Config.instance
  }

  private getConfigFromEnv(): Configuration {
    dotenv.config()

    return {
      port: Number(process.env.PORT) || 8000,
      gamesExternalAPIURL: process.env.GAMES_EXTERNAL_API_URL || '',
    }
  }
}
```

With this test:

```
import Config from '@config/Config'

describe('config', () => {
  const instance = Config.getInstance()

  it('should match snapshot', () => {
    expect(instance.get()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

That singleton class works well in runtime, but in the test, the getInstance returns undefined and breaks the test. I've already tested if the getInstance is called and it's actually not called in the test. The error:

[image]

Comment: For me its works. It might be a jest setup issue then: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-mhqb9b?file=src/config.test.ts

Comment: I can't see the difference that could be causing the problem. My configuration: https://gist.github.com/ThallyssonKlein/5a97d6ede584f443f340de73a04fd528

Comment: How does your jest setup look like? In my linked example is a little jest setup inside the package.json.